# How to wait button clicks for a while in android

Tags: android, multithreading, algorithm, button, text-to-speech

I am developing an application for blinds.

I have 4 screen sized buttons (overlapped). Every step of program one button will be clickable and every button has more than one job.

My program starts with a voice (Android TTS engine). Like "please touch screen to do x". After this step I want to wait 3 seconds for button click, if button is not clicked vocalize "please touch screen to do y" and wait 3 seconds again for job y. (x and y is first button's jobs).

Button should do one of them according to touching screen. But how can I wait 3 seconds for button click and continue to vocalize next options and wait 3 seconds again.

If first button is clicked, it will disappear-button 2 will be clickable- and TTS engine will start to vocalize second buttons options. Application will be work like this but I am stuck in waiting button clicks part.

Comment: Do a [postDelayed](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). Cancel it on click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would advise you to use android.os.Handler instead. In your case you could do something like this:

```
public void onCreate() {
  this.handler = new Handler()
  playTheVoiceOfThingX()
  viewToTap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
      doThingX();
    }
  });
  handler.postDelayed(new PrepareThingYTask(), 3000);
}
class PrepareThingYTask() implements Runnable {
   viewToTap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick() {
        doThingY();
     }
   });
   handler.postDelayed(new PrepareThingZTask(), 3000);
}

class PrepareThingZTask() implements Runnable {
   ....
}
```

A good reminder, the runnable executed by the handler can be executed in UIThread, so no heavy work on it, or create a different looper to run it.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could solve your problem with busy wait.
So after you first vocalized "please touch screen..." you would start a background thread which waits for a specific amount of time, like so:

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //vocalize
                    }
                });
        }
    }).start();
```

As you can see, from within the thread a new runnable is started after 3 seconds which again runs on the UI Thread. This, because I think I remember that you should make such sound-things (depending on your method of how to play the file / sound) only from the UI Thread.

However, this is just an idea and I could not test-run my code!
But I hope I inspired you!

Regards
Me